# Decimal changes to comma when inserting formula into Excel from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to put an if-formula into a cell.

I get an error 1004 when I try to run the code (relevant part below).

```
n = 1.2
.Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=if(" & .Cells(2, 3).Address(False, False) & "=1," & n & ",na())"
```

If I put the formula into a variable, I can see that VBA "saves" the 1.2 as "1,2" which is interpreted as if there are too many arguments in the formula.

So instead of

```
=if(C2=1,1.2,na())
```

I get

```
=if(C2=1,1,2,na())
```

If I manually enter

```
.Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=if(" & .Cells(2, 3).Address(False, False) & "=0,1.2" & ",na())"
```

The formula comes out right in Excel, but as I need to loop over a data, that is not a sustainable solution.

As I am based in Europe, I suspect regional settings being a part of the problem, but as those are company-wide, I can't fiddle with that without causing a different set of problems.

I tried

```
n = 1.2
.Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=if(" & .Cells(2, 3).Address(False, False) & "=1," & CDbl(n) & ",na())"
```

Comment: If you would manually type the comma as a decimal and, presumably, a semi-colon as the list separator, you could use `FormulaLocal` and enter the formula as you would type it?

Comment: Just change `List Separator` in Regional Settings to semi-colon and just use it in your functions instead of comma. Point or comma will no matter in your numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Rory, looks like that works perfectly!